# Is there a standard for compressing Media Type (MIME, Content-Type)

Tags: javascript, http, compression, mime-types, media-type

I am compressing the [Media Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) to 72 bits.

I intend to do this by taking the first 72 bits of a SHA1 hash of the Media Type, and then use a loo-up table, for example:

```
SHA1HashFunc("application/ogg").slice(0,18)

"2d8a15e521a1c8115a"
```

It seems like the type of thing that there might be a standard for, but I can't seem to find it if there is.

**Is there a pre-existing standard to compress the Media Type?**

Comment: Maybe http2 HPACK could be of use? haven't digged into the specification and don't know exactly what it's doing

Comment: @Endless thanks, good tip, I haven't grokked it yet but I think the Huffman Coding it uses is more applicable to much longer strings.

Comment: There actually is [a registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/core-parameters/core-parameters.xhtml#content-formats) mapping select media types to a uint16. But it is meant for CoAP, not HTTP. Is there any reason for the 72bit constraint?

Comment: @DaSourcerer thanks, yes, should be <=72 bits to be precise

Comment: @DaSourcerer and that looks good, but doesn't seem complete (unless I'm missing something). E.g. can't see `text/html`

Comment: Yes, it is only for select media types. The [full registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) is huge and is covering far more than is relevant for either CoAP or HTTP. The question still stands: Why do you need to compress this in the first place?

Comment: @DaSourcerer a good question. I don't have time to answer right now, will aim to soon